# dynamically create class object by using assemblyname and type of class

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, reflection

I have a console application in which I declared a class which is defined under a namespace. I want to create an instance of that class at runtime using assemblyname and class name. I tried the below code

```
var objAssembly = Assembly.Load(assemblyName);
var objType = objAssembly.GetType(className);
var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(objType);
```

But it is not working. Below is the class structure

```
namespace ReportService.ReportWriters
{
    class ExcelWriter : IReportWriter
    {
    }
}
```

I passed assembly name = ExcelWriter
         class name = ReportService.ReportWriters

Comment: Could you be more specific about the "it's not working" part?

Comment: The exception is - Could not load file or assembly 'ExcelWriter' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: The part about "cannot find the file specified" is more or less self-explanatory, right?

Comment: I updated my question.Please check it

Comment: Is `ExcelWriter.dll` signed? Is it in the directory from which your program is started? Does it have dependencies?

Comment: No it it is not there in the directory. It does not have any dependency

Comment: If it's not in the directory from which your program is started, what configuration do you have to help your running program find the DLL? Did you try copying the DLL into the directory from which your program runs? This would be the first thing I'd try to isolate the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe tou should get all types and find `ExcelWriter` class and initialize it:

```
var objAssembly = Assembly.Load(assemblyName);
var objType = objAssembly.GetTypes().First(x => x.Name == "ExcelWriter");
var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(objType);
```

Or use [Assembly.CreateInstance()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/system.reflection.assembly.createinstance(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
var namespaceName = "ReportService.ReportWriters";
var objAssembly = Assembly.Load(assemblyName);
var obj = objAssembly.CreateInstance(objAssembly.GetName().Name.Replace(" ","_") + "." + namespaceName + "." + "ExcelWriter");
```

**NOTE:** If assemblyName contains spaces compiler converts spaces to `_` character.

**NOTE:** Add `using System.Linq;` to usings.

Comment: I tried both condition.Is not working.Giving exception
"Could not load file or assembly 'ExcelWriter' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

Comment: What returns `objAssembly.GetTypes()` method at your code?

Comment: Assembly.Load(assemblyName);
is giving exception mentioned above. The dll is not there in bin folder.Is this causing the issue?

Comment: Try [Assembly.FromFile()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.loadfile(v=vs.110).aspx) method and give it your assembly file location.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because your class does not contain any public or internal default constructor.

create public default constructor and then try, It should work normally.

Check this article -

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83(v=vs.110).aspx